# Where to sleep at Frankfurt airport

Tags: air-travel, sleeping, fra

I arrive at Frankfurt international airport in the morning (9 am) and I have to wait 10 hours until my next flight. Also I don't have a visa to get out of the airport. What is the best way to get some sleep in the airport?

Comment: [On the official website](http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/frankfurt_airport/en/transfer/stopover.html) there is some info, but I don't find it very helpful

Comment: Having been there, I found none. At least none where I would feel somewhat confident that my bags would still be there when I wake up.

Comment: There is no any place made in the airport for the passengers who can sleep comfortably..just like others you have to sit in the waiting area or find a corner seat so that you will not disturbed by others..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [sleepinginairports.net](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/frankfurt.htm), there are some seats without armrests in the hall between Terminal C and B, and security and cleaning staff will probably not bother you. Additionally, there are two lounges that are open to everyone (for a fee)

Comment: Any chance, you can provide more details, where these free lounges at Fraport are located? Thanks!

Comment: @trejder: there are details on the website I linked to here: http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/frankfurt.htm#lounge

Answer (score 5):

It's good to find a corner or a place near the wall and lay there. You can use your rucksack as a pillow, not very comfortable, but assuring, that noone would take it away. But you shouldn't be concerned about robberies in Germany. It's good to have a sleeping pad for such situations.

It's quite normal in such places, that there are a lot of people having to wait long. And some of them are tired. In case someone makes you problems, you can say you have pain in the back because of sitting too long.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from March 6, 2017, there will be a hotel in the transit area ([website](http://www.mycloud.de/)); it is the first such hotel at a German airport. Rooms can be booked from three hours upwards, and check-in/check-out are possible at any time between 5 am and 11 pm. Considering that there are no scheduled flights during the night, this should not be a serious limitation in practice.

Rooms are not cheap, however – apparently, prices start from € 80 for three hours in a single room. Therefore, the free alternatives mentioned in the other answers may still be interesting.